# Wordpress Get Post Types, custom posts types only

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Using Custom Post Type UI-plugin, I want to push any custom post types to a ACF-field that is used by a posts page (so user can choose which post type to display). Now I'm getting it to work with code below, however a bunch of other "Junk" comes with it. Any idea how to get rid of that and just add the original "post" and any "custom post types"?

functions.php

```
function acf_load_post_type_choices( $field ) {

    $post_types = get_post_types();
    if($post_types) {

    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting    

         if ( is_array( $post_types[0] ) ) {
            $getTypeSlugs =  $post_types[0];
            $getTypeNames =  $post_types[0];
            // Array( supported_format_1, supported_format_2 ... )
        } else {

        }

        array_unshift($getTypeSlugs,'all','standard');
        array_unshift($getTypeNames,'all','standard');
        //create a string from formatSlug
        $values = implode("\n", $post_types );
        //create a string from category Name
        $labels = implode("\n",  $post_types);
        //Add an "all"-options

        //devide the strings into seperate objects
        $values = explode("\n", $values);
        $labels = explode("\n", $labels);
        $labels = array_map('ucfirst', $labels);

        // loop through array and add to field 'choices'

           foreach( array_combine($values, $labels ) as $value => $label ) {
                $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;       
           }

        // return the field
        return $field;
    }

}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=posts_by_type', 'acf_load_post_type_choices', 1);
```

Result:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

My custom pages:
[image]

Comment: If you are getting those returned by get_post_types, then that must mean these “junk” elements _are_ custom post types. Not your “own” maybe, but created by other plugins in use by the system. If you wanted to filter those, then you would need to find a way to differentiate them form the “others” - by a different criterion than just “is a custom post type”.

Comment: I see, so I have to look if there is something in the CPT UI-plugin forexample and target that with some $args?

Comment: There is a function `cptui_get_post_type_data();` maybe I could use this?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This seems a bit more complicated than it needs to be, why not just add them manually to the field if it's going to be those 3 post types or maybe just change:</strike>

```
$post_types = get_post_types();
```

to

```
$post_types = [
    'post' => 'post',
    'page' => 'page',
    'people' => 'people'
];
```

All the get_post_types() function is doing it getting the names of the post types anyway?

Ok possible solution that might work for you  depending on how dynamic you want this to be.

If you return objects from the get_post_types() function

```
$all_post_types = get_post_types($args, 'objects');
```

And give your post types a description to differentiate them e.g. include_in_select then you can loop through the ones that match that description and push them to an array, then use that array in your original function.

```
$post_types_no_junk = [];
foreach($all_post_types as $post_type){
    if($post_type->description === 'include_in_select'){
        $post_types_no_junk[] = $post_type;
    }
}
```

Not ideal but might be enough to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, well if I wanted something static that would work, but I need to add them dynamically :)

Comment: I understand but if it is dynamic and you are only allowing post, page and people if you added a new post type how would how would your code know whether to include it or not. With Custom post types the basic way to differentiate them is if they are builtin (core Wordpress) or not. Maybe an options page with a field showing all post types junk and all allowing you to select which fields appear in the the ACF field on the posts page?

Comment: I edited my answer with a different solution that might suit you.